# How can i rotate a spaceship back to it's original rotation to face the original position?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The spaceship start moving from point A. The spaceship is facing the moving direction. 
Now when i click one on the L key i want that the spaceship will rotate and will face to the original position it was start moving from. But even if the spaceship is now rotated by axis Z or Y or X to rotate it first to the regular rotation values and to face to the start moving position.
[image: Explain]

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Control : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int rotationSpeed = 75;
    public int movementspeed = 10;
    public int thrust = 10;

    private bool isPKeyDown = false;
    private float acceleration = .0f;
    private Vector3 previousPosition = Vector3.zero;
    private Rigidbody _rigidbody;
    private Vector3 originalPosition;
    private Quaternion originalRotation;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        originalPosition = transform.position;
        originalRotation = transform.rotation;

        _rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        Debug.Log("Acc Speed: " + thrust);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        var v3 = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Vertical"), Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0.0f);
        transform.Rotate(v3 * rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        transform.position += transform.forward * Time.deltaTime * movementspeed;

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Z))
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward * rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

        if (Input.GetKey("p"))
        {
            isPKeyDown = Input.GetKey("p");
            float distance = Vector3.Distance(previousPosition, transform.position);
            acceleration = distance / Mathf.Pow(Time.deltaTime, 2);

            previousPosition = transform.position;
            _rigidbody.AddRelativeForce(0f, 0f, thrust, ForceMode.Acceleration);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey("l"))
        {
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, originalRotation, 0);
            //StartCoroutine(TurnShip(transform, transform., originalRotation.eulerAngles, 1));
            //transform.position += transform.forward * Time.deltaTime * movementspeed;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator TurnShip(Transform ship, Vector3 startAngle, Vector3 endAngle, float smooth)
    {
        float lerpSpeed = 0;

        while (lerpSpeed < 1)
        {
            ship.eulerAngles = Vector3.Lerp(startAngle, endAngle, lerpSpeed);
            lerpSpeed += Time.deltaTime * smooth;
            yield return null;
        }
    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        if (isPKeyDown)
        {
            GUI.Label(new Rect(100, 100, 200, 200), "Acc Speed: " + acceleration);
        }
    }
}
```

This is where i click the L button but i tried some things but can't yet find how to do it.

The main goal is if i click once on L the spaceship should automatic rotate if needed and move back to the original position and then land on ground. L stand for landing that's the main goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a variable on top -

```
...
private Vector3 originalPosition;
private Quaternion originalRotation;

private bool landShip = false;
...
```

And use following code in `update` function -

```
if (Input.GetKey("l"))
{
   landShip = true;
   //StartCoroutine(TurnShip(transform, transform., originalRotation.eulerAngles, 1));
   //transform.position += transform.forward * Time.deltaTime * movementspeed;
}
if(landShip){
   transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, originalRotation, 0.5f); 
}
```

Once the spaceship lands, set the `landShip` value back to `false`.